# How can I show a different component based on the current language (React / i18n)

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

Can anybody tell me why this code doesn't work?

EDIT: I can't use Keys, because I want to format the text.

VSC Shows this Error:
Property 'match' does not exist on type 'ITranslationContext'. ts(2339)

```
export const Preparation = () => {
  const i18n = useTranslation()
  const locale = i18n.match(["de", "fr", "it"])

  switch (locale) {
    case "de":
      return <PreparationGerman />
    case "fr":
      return <PreparationFrench />
    case "it":
      return <PreparationItalian />
  }
  return <PreparationEnglish />
}


const PreparationGerman = () => (
    <h1>German</h1>
)

const PreparationFrench = () => (
    <h1>French</h1>
)

const PreparationItalian = () => (
    <h1>Italian</h1>
)

const PreparationEnglish = () => (
    <h1>English</h1>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `match()` method searches a `string` for a match against a regular expression, and returns the matches, as an Array object.

Please check the documentation of `i18n` for a suitable method.

However, you do not need to create separate components. Instead, create a key (say `lang`) for all the languages and use that to display the language inside the component.

```html
 <h1>{i18n.translate('lang')}</h1>
```

**Edit**:

The i18n is an object which contains the locale property.

update the locale definition to:

```js
const {locale} = i18n;
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!

I use keys, but in this case I want complex formatting.

Comment: Can you please share the value received inside `i18n`?

Comment: Do you mean this?

availableLocales: (4) ["de-CH", "en", "fr-CH", "it-CH"]
defaultLocale: "de-CH"
elem: ƒ elem(key, values)
locale: "de-CH"
text: ƒ text(key, values)
__proto__: Object

Comment: Yes, thanks!! Here you can see the i18n is an `object`, which contains the locale property. Updating the answer to get the locale value.